# Rowfilter in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Web application, [asp.net] i am using rowfileter, can i write two columns like...

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name='sasi' and lastname='surya'";
```

is this possible, can you help me.

Comment: Have you tried it? (The answer is yes, btw. See http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ for a set of worked examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can row filter by below code:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Column1 = " + value1 + " AND Column2 = " + value2;
```

Comment: i will check and inform you later

Comment: Be careful; if value1 and value2 are strings then you need single quotes. If value1 and value2 are dates then consider using an invariant datetime format.

Comment: for dates can i place sing quotes